# Design Patterns to model complex decision graph

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, unit-testing, object-oriented-design, architectural-patterns

I am currently building a piece of code that creates side-effects based on input parameters.
It has around ten input parameters and about six available side-effects.
Based on the input parameters, the chosen side-effects - one or multiple - differ.

I have started developing this code test first with a context/specification framework, because every input parameter is basically a context.

The resulting code so far is a deeply nested if-else structure.

I have implemented about 30% so far and the code - and the tests even more - are getting very complex, unwieldy and hard to understand. So much that I am doubting this is the correct approach.
The main problem are actually the tests, because I keep repeating the conditions for some of the deeper nested input parameters as well as for the resulting side-effects.

**Are there design patterns for building *and testing* this kind of "decision graph"?**

Please note that the input parameters are not fixed values. A lot of the logic is relativ, i.e. if input parameter 1 is less than input parameter 2.

The current output from my tests can be seen here: https://cloud.fire-development.com/f/12bcba0439/?raw=1
You can see that there is a lot of repetition, making it hard to reason about what it actually does.

Comment: One of the things I'm wondering is if there are coarser conditions you can identify that determines, say, when a cow should and shouldn't have a leave/receive event instead of a series of nested conditionals, like "cow should have receive event if this is true", independent of all these nested events. That's what I'd try to identify to simplify all of this is to look for things you can check independent of a complex series of nested events: invariants you can tie to other properties instead of a series of cascading events.

Comment: That's typically how I cut down the cases to test against. The property relationships I generally verify are like, "This should never be zero no matter what", instead of, "If this event happens and that event happens and this is the case, this should not be zero." Then you can turn it into like, "make sure things are still in a valid state" instead of checking all kinds of individual things in every single possible case.

Comment: Great input thanks. What I am basically doing here is grouping. I have health events of cows that are time stamped. Because of external factors, all events have the same cow ID. Those events need to be grouped. Each group represents a different cow. Because the external IDs are all the same, I can't use it for grouping and I need to use other identifiers. And there are a lot of things that determine if an event belongs to the same cow as another event or to a different cow. Grouping those conditions into a broader set of conditions is a good idea, but I am not sure, this actually is possible.

Comment: Identifying what a valid cow is, may in fact be the better approach, although there are outcomes other than cows as well...

Comment: I see. Also it occurred to me that if you want to test really precisely, a cow could be in a valid state but it could still be in the wrong state for a given time. Come to think of it, I think the only reason I never tested so many cases is because my testing wasn't as thorough as yours. :-( Apologies --
 I'm really stumped but hoping some people will answer this one.

Comment: Yeah, this is a core logic of the application and we are processing millions of events, so this needs to work correctly as we can't verify the result manually...

Comment: One of the things I tend to do is, as said, my unit and integration tests aren't nearly as thorough as yours, but my `asserts` are. I tend to reserve `assert` for those really low-level sanity checks interleaved directly into the implementation itself. That makes even the unit testing checking things on a coarser level, like "trigger these events and make sure things are valid", but the `asserts` check all the most granular and gross details related to making sure all states are set appropriately at all times. There's a bit of redundancy there between asserts and unit tests...

Comment: But I use the asserts for those lowest-level sanity checks that are most useful to directly interleave into the implementation itself. The impression I get from your test is kind of that you're checking all the possible conditions externally that I tend to `assert` internally... that might actually be the superior practice but some internal `asserts` here and there might make those tests a bit more manageable.

Comment: I don't see how I actually could use assert in this scenario. It's not as if there are invalid parameter combinations. However, thinking about your comments made me realize that I am violating the SRP here: I am trying to detect potential Data Entry Errors - potential, so they might still be correct - and I am deciding whether to add an event to an existing cow or a new one and when adding it to an existing cow, I am also deciding to which one. Furthermore, when adding a new cow or adding an event to an existing cow, I am also deciding how this is reflected on the cow.

Comment: So I would say, first of all, I have to extract the detection for potential Data Entry errors into its own piece of logic. Next, I might want to extract the logic that decides if an event should be added to an existing cow or create a new one

Comment: In my case I sprinkle `asserts` all over the place to verify post-conditions, like `assert(the cow should have no leave event)` directly inlined inside the code implementing all this stuff instead of an external test to validate post-conditions. It does kind of raise the question of what I should be asserting vs. unit testing, and also I tend to have some redundancy between what my unit tests verify vs. what I directly assert inside my functions (though the unit test verifications have the benefit of running even in release builds, while the asserts have the benefit of not slowing them down).

Comment: ... but it's kind of my compromised way to allow me to avoid having to check so many things in the unit tests. The asserts take care of the most granular kind of pre and post-condition sanity checks on the functions called in general (including by the unit tests). I also do that partially to avoid having to white box everything for the tests while still keeping those ultra-granular sanity checks. I'm not sure if this is such a good practice, but it's my way to kind of sanity-check all kinds of things that can be caught debugging without writing enormous unit tests.

Comment: My domain is very different but I work with polygonal meshes, for example, and when a polygon is created, I assert inside the function that the new polygon has a default surface (as it should), that it has no external data associated, things of this sort. I don't actually bother to check such granular/internal things in my unit tests. They do, however, call the polygon creation functions and check that the mesh is still in an overall valid state and that the new polygon indeed exists after the call, but unit tests are a little more "black-boxed" and asserts are totally "white-boxed".

Answer (score 3):

From implementation point view, Martin & Eric's [Specification](https://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) pattern may help. If possible, try to break down your rules and group them to smaller ones, and use "Logical Expressions for Composite Specifications" to converge them. By this way, you can test each individual small logical unit one by one.

Also, there're some Commercial off-the-shelf solution for decision DSLs such as Drool from redhat.

As for the testing, apart from breaking down, the [Data-Driven Test](http://xunitpatterns.com/Data-Driven%20Test.html) seems quite fit with your problem. The scenario to use this pattern is

> "essentially the same test with slight different system inputs and
>   verify that the actual output varies accordingly"

There're also lots of commercial or open source solutions for the testing area, such as Fit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am already using data driven tests where it makes sense. The specification pattern might be a good idea in parts, yes. Breaking down the rules is the first step now